# Show that $\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(r-z)^2}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives, holomorphic-functions

I'm asked to show that $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(r-z)^2}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{N}$, and am given the hint that for any $z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{N}$ the series is uniform on some neighbourhood of $z$.

Someone has asked the same question here:

[Showing $\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(r-z)^2}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581073/showing-sum-r-1-infty-frac1r-z2-is-holomorphic-on-mathbbc-back)

but I haven't been shown the result that the answer uses. Does anyone know a better way to do it?

I know I can use Morera's theorem to show that $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma} \sum_{r=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(r-z)^2} \ \text{dz} = 0 $ for any closed path $\gamma$, but I'm not sure how to justify exchanging the integral and the sum for any arbitrary path, when the convergence is only uniform on some neighbourhood of each point - not necessarily along the whole arbitrary closed path.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there already is an answer, it is probably easiest to understand the result used there.

Comment: HINT: Write $z=x+iy$ and verify Wirtinger's equations (equivalent to $\overline\partial f=0$).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following simpler fact. If

- $f_n$ are holomorphic in $\Omega$,
- $f_n\to f$ uniformly in $\Omega$,
- $f_n'\to g$ uniformly in $\Omega$,

then $f$ is holomorphic with $f'=g$.

Then check that with $f_n$ equal to the partial sum and $\Omega\Subset\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb N$ the assumptions are verified.